# One or more categories are configured with Verbose trace logging - Can't get rid of error

Tags: logging, diagnostics

I am having the following error being reported on a SharePoint 2016 install:

> One or more categories are configured with Verbose trace logging.

Explanation:

> The following categories are configured with verbose
>   logging levels. This may adversely affect disk usage and performance.
>   General

I tried fixing the problem by following the instructions found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh204610.aspx) (i.e. reset event throttling of diagnostic logging to default levels), but it does not seem to fix the problem. I wonder if this is a false positive, perhaps a bug in SP 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions provided by Microsoft are not that clear.

The issue is that I had a custom solution, the Forms-Based Authentication (FBA) Pack, installed on SharePoint. By default this solution does verbose logging.

What I did was to expand all of the items in the list for logging and find out which one was set to do verbose logging. Then I selected the item in question, and THEN I changed the log level from verbose to INFORMATION.

All fixed :)